# How to display unicode characters correctly in MySQL Workbench for Mac?

Tags: mysql, unicode, mysql-workbench

I use *MySQL Workbench 6.3.9 64bit Community*.
I can see unicode characters in web app correctly. But I don't see it correctly at data grid when querying. How to fix it?
[image]
(See data row has id=7)

`&#272;i&#7879;n l&#7841;nh gia d&#7909;ng` it means `Điện lạnh gia dụng`

`&#272;i&#7879;n l&#7841;nh` it means `Điện lạnh`

Comment: Do you mean that Workbench does not render VARCHAR columns as HTML? Why should it?

Comment: I set it is `NVARCHAR`, not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: That doesn't matter. What I mean is that a MySQL client is not a web browser. It your column contains HTML it'll just print the raw source as-is, it will not render it.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your idea. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Things like `&#7841;` are called "html entities".  They are *not* generated by MySQL or Workbench, but by something else.  Fonts don't matter, either.

Some possible sources:

- PHP, using `htmlentities()`
- PHP, using `json_encode()`, but with out the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option.

Suggest you walk back the chain of where the data came from.

Answer (score -1):

Try going to Preferences -> fonts and change the results pane font to Arial...the default should be Helvetica.